# Field Editor Datatables currency

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to create a currency field on Editor form?

I put a mask `{ label: "Salary:", name: "salary", type: "mask", mask: "#,##0.00", reverse: true },`

This creates a fixed mask-like `_,___.__` 
if I type 10 the result is `1,0` 
if I type 100 the result is `1,00`

How to create correctly the currency field?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution:

`{ label: "Salary:", name: "salary", type: "mask", mask: "#,##0.00", maskOptions: { reverse: true} }`